# Restore Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I had a virtual machine on Hyper-V. I copied 1 VHDX and 2 AVHDX (This VM had 2 snapshots) to a disk drive. Now I want to run latest version of VM on other Hyper-V. As I understand I should merge them using Hyper-V Manager. I tried to merge VHDX with 1st AVHDX and then VHDX with 2nd AVHDX. I both cases I had clean VM (what was before 1st snapshot). What's right way to get latest version of VM and run it?[image]

Answer (score 3):

To get the newest version you would start the merge with the latest AVHDX, and merge that with its parent. repeat process with the other AVHDX and you would then have a useable VHDX with all checkpoints merged.

See the guide here for steps https://blog.workinghardinit.work/2014/08/29/manually-merging-hyper-v-checkpoints/